# Associating already existent Entity with new Entity through API

Tags: rest, api, api-design

I have interesting situation here, which I'd like to draw your opinions upon. I'm designing a REST API and here are the Resources pertaining to this question.

1. I have an *User Entity*, which I create through POST `/users/` and Read-Update-Delete(RUD) by `/users/:user-id`
2. I have an *Event Entity* which I create through POST `/events/` and Read-Update-Delete(RUD) by `/events/:event-id`
3. Now, multiple Users can be associated to multiple Events. This is why, there is a *Member Entity* which references a `user-id` and `event-id`. Basically, every time a *User* attends an *Event*, he as a unique *Member* profile for that Event. *Member* is created through `/events/:event-id/members` and modified through `/events/:event-id/members/:member-id`
4. I have *Mini Events* which are parts of Events. A *Mini Event* is *NOT* an *Event*, but instead a part of an *Event*. They are created through `/events/:event-id/minievent` and modified through `/events/:event-id/minievent/:minievent-id`

**Here's my question**

I wish to associate *Members* of an *Event* to a *Mini Event* of naturally, the same *Hackathon*.

The first way that comes to mind is **POST `event/event:id/minievents/:minievents/members`** BUT the Member entity I wish to associate to this *Mini Event* has been created when I created this *Member* for this *Event*. Naturally, you cannot associate a Member to a Mini-Event before creating a Member for the main Event in the first place.

I believe using **POST `event/event:id/minievents/:minievents/members`** would be incorrect as it would mean *creating* members but they have already been created.

I wish to associate Members of an Event to a Mini Event. What would be the most RESTful way to do this?

Note: *Mini Events* have a different schema than *Events*, they are different entities and not interchangeable. Don't suggest making Mini Events and Events the same thing.

Comment: `Naturally, you cannot associate a Member to a Mini-Event before creating a Member for the main Event in the first place.` -- So you need **two** REST calls, right?

Comment: The other thing you can do is drop REST for this specific situation, and just make a non-REST-ful POST.  REST is primarily document-oriented CRUD; if what you are doing is not document-oriented CRUD, REST might not be the best fit.

Comment: ^^Yes, one to create a Member for the Event and then associate that Member to a Mini Event that exists for that Hackathon

Comment: @RobertHarvey ^^Could you write an answer instead?